# Online dictionaries that group terminology by topic?

Tags: discussion

You can learn terminology related to specific areas of knowledge ('AOK's') by reading wikis and online encyclopedias. This is because exploring any AOK always involves learning terminology.

There are topical dictionaries which focus on a particular AOK or small group of interrelated of AOKs. (e.g. Dictionary of Gems and Gemology)

Are there any online dictionaries that allow users to select a topic and see a comprehensive list of its related terminology?

Comment: Excellent question. Not exactly what you're asking for, in three distinct ways, but Roget's Thesaurus was historically 1) organized purely by topic (-not- alphabetized), 2) in that state, only hard copy (not on-line), and 3) about abstract words that are synonyms (eg integrity, honesty, trustworthiness) rather than a collection of words in a sub field (eg sailing terms - bowline, starboard, tiller). I'm wondering if one just needs to google for 'sailing terms' to get such a list, which may not be as comprehensive as a dictionary.

Comment: I try to search for specialized vocabulary by using the word glossary.